# How do I fill an array with consecutive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, input

I would like to fill an array using consecutive integers. I have created an array that contains as much indexes as the user enters:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int numOfValues = in.nextInt();

int [] array = new int[numOfValues];
```

How do i fill this array with consecutive numbers starting from 1?
All help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Please use proper naming conventions. Make it `numOfValues`. Classes start with a capital letter, not variables

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since Java 8

```
//                               v end, exclusive
int[] array = IntStream.range(1, numOfValues + 1).toArray();
//                            ^ start, inclusive
```

The `range` is in increments of 1. The javadoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-).

Or use [`rangeClosed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-)

```
//                                     v end, inclusive
int[] array = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numOfValues).toArray();
//                                  ^ start, inclusive
```

Answer (score 4):

The simple way is:

```
int[] array = new int[NumOfValues];
for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
    array[k] = k + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> 2 + i);
// arr ==> int[5] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You now have an empty array

So you need to iterate over each position (0 to size-1) placing the next number into the array.

```
for(int x=0; x<NumOfValues; x++){ // this will iterate over each position
     array[x] = x+1; // this will put each integer value into the array starting with 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing. If I want to do the same with reverse:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
        for(int i = 5; i>0;i--) {
            array[i-1]= i;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

I got the normal order again..

Comment: *You got the normal order again..* - So? what could we do?

Answer (score -2):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int numOfValues = in.nextInt();

int[] array = new int[numOfValues];

int add = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    array[i] = 1 + add;

    add++;

    System.out.println(array[i]);

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.