# Populate an array within a specific range

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I wanna populate an array with integers within 2000-3000.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 int[] nums = new int[1000];
 for (int y = 0; y < nums.length; y++) {

  for (int i = 2000; i < 3000; i++) {
   nums[y] = i;
  }
 }
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```

I got an array with full of 2999.

What's the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need just the second loop and you can use `i - 2000` as the index, eg: `nums[i-2000]=i;`

Comment: There's a post that can give you the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28490904/2625912

Comment: its easy your num[y] value always equals to your second loop's last value i =2999 , example for y =3  exeuction of your 2nd loop block will look like this y[3] =1, y[3] = 2, .... y[3] = 2999

Comment: This is where using your debugger should have helped you answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're populating the same cell again and again. Your array size is 1000, but your range is 1001: 3000 - 2000 + 1 = 1001

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums = new int[1001];
    for(int y=0;y<nums.length;y++) {
        nums[y]= y + 2000;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about Java 8 solution?

```
IntStream.range(2000, 3001).toArray(); // [2000, 2001, ... 3000]
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need nested loop to do that just do

```
 int[] nums = new int[1000];        

 for(int i=2000; i<3000; i++) {
       nums[i-2000]=i;
 }     

 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

you get 2999 because your loop ends `i<3000` , just change it to `i<=3000` and also increase the array length to

```
int[] nums = new int[1001];
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/76eBsZ)

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you can translate your code into human language.

Breaking down your code, you have two loops. One is:

```
int[] nums = new int[1000];
  for (int y = 0; y < nums.length; y++) {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

Your idea in the first loop is to iterate through the whole length of the array.

> "For each index in the array..."

Then, you have another loop inside the array iterator:

```
for (int i = 2000; i < 3000; i++) {
  nums[y] = i;
}
```

Here, you are trying to put a number from 2000 to 2999 into index `y` of the array.

> "In **index y** of the array, put values 2000 to 2999."

The previous values are overwritten for every value you put. This ultimately ends up as:

> "Put 2999 in **index y** of the array."

Putting them together:

> "For each **index y** in the array, put 2999."

---

Check [TDG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38683120/6657913) for the proper way of writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with 1 loop.As mentioned by @silentprogrammer , you need to increase array size by 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int var=2000;
        int[] nums = new int[1001];
        for (int y = 0; y < nums.length; y++) {
            nums[y]=var++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
```