# Java Filling array with numbers from 1 to X with a loop (not random numbers)

Tags: java, arrays

I know that I can declare and initialize each array and transfer the numbers from 1 to X, but is it possible to fill an array with numbers from 1 to X with a loop?

I only know how to fill the array with 1 certain or random numbers, f. ex. like that:

```
public class NurTests {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       int [] arr = new int[100];
       int value = 1;
       for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
           arr[i] = value;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `arr[i] = i+1` for 1 -> arr.length, `arr[i] = i` for 0 -> arr.length

Comment: You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490869/how-do-i-fill-an-array-with-consecutive-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fill the array with a range of `1 - N`:

```
public class NurTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] arr = new int[100];
        int value = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = value;
            value ++;
        }
    }
}
```

A simpler way to do it, you could just remove the middle man:

```
public class NurTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int [] arr = new int[100];
       for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
           arr[i] = i + 1;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: if this answers your question accept the answer by clicking the check mark by my answer